# Error 503, CiviCRM 5.32.2 on Joomla 3.9.27 & PHP 7.3.27

Tags: joomla, installation

Error 503, CiviCRM 5.32.2 on Joomla 3.9.27 & PHP 7.3.27

Hello,

After successfully installing CiviCRM on a local test environment, I am trying to install CiviCRM on my hosted production Joomla environment.  The CiviCRM database tables are created, and the media/civicrm folder is present.  However after several minutes the Joomla installer returns a page with error 503.  I can't seem to find any error logs, but the resources indicate a good amount of I/O operations.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I may tweak the server (or files) to complete the installation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a log file under `media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog` ?

Comment: Thank you for looking into it,.  
No, I do not have any files under that directory besides a folder labelled 'templates_c" which itself is empty.